# Objective C using twitter profiles in my own app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, profiles

I'm making a video based app, I want to be able to allow the users to use their twitter profiles to be the profiles used in the app

I'm fairly new to app development/obj c, so would really appreciate any help
by any chance is there a way to use the built in twitter login feature in ios?

Thanks alot :)

EDIT: 
Thanks for your help i'm going to look into the links you gave me and see how i get on :)

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest taking a look at a CocoaPod called [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter). It makes consuming the Twitter API incredibly easy and straightforward. The repository's readme also gives some great examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [this tutorial](http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/).

Can also use [UIActivityViewController](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/uiactivityviewcontroller-sharing-content-on-ios-6-part-1.html) to share with twitter.

Hope this may help you.